# Bootstrap 3 grid with different height in each item - is it solvable using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a grid of thumbnails, where each thumbnail has an image and a label. It works fine if all the labels have the same length, because then all the thumbnails have the same height:

http://www.bootply.com/iSqwWyx5ms

However, if I shorten the rightmost thumbnail's text, part of the row below gets pushed into a new row, as shown here:

http://www.bootply.com/Wqd021aaeM

What I would like is the second row to start from the lowest point in which the first row ended.

I know I can solve it with JavaScript - find the longest thumbnail in each row and set the other thumbnails to have that height. Question is, do I have any way of doing it, or something else that can solve my problem, using only with CSS?

Update: I don't know beforehand how many items I have in one row. For example, on a small screen I'd have 2 items in a row, while on a bigger screen it'll be 3, so solutions which set when a new row starts aren't good for me.

Comment: I just answered this same question here yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571062/gap-in-bootstap-stacked-rows/24571644#24571644

Comment: Your welcome, I gave you a little more detail in the answer below.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should use `.clearfix`, as described at the Grid responsive resets section of the Bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Comment: Thanks gbellmann. Sorry, but I should've been more clear on my question. I don't know how many items there will be in a row, so I can't really know where to put the clearfix. Please let me know if you have any more ideas.

Comment: Combining with @jme11's comment, your solution is valid. I don't know how many items will be in a row, but I do know how many items will be in a row for a specific size, so using "visible-md" on a specific clearfix does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 36):

If you don't know how many columns you have, you can do:

```
.row.fix {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:100%; /*not always necessary*/
}
```

**Working fiddle:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/wqdm1jjt/

Example:
[image]

Author: Juan Miguel

Comment: All these answers, and yours is the only one that works responsively - thanks! :D

Comment: boooyaaa, until BS4. Awesome solution. Don't care if it doesn't support legacy browsers

Comment: THIS IS THE BEST ANSWER!!!!!!!!!!! 6HOURS TRYING TO MAKE IT WORK!!!!!! this simple code made my day!!

Comment: Nice, simple and effective. Excellent answer!

Answer (score 7):

I think it's better to use some few row of `js`. With CSS you could only have a new "row" using `clearfix` class (as answered before), but each div will have different height. 
If you wish to set the same height to each **dynamic** div, I think you could do it only by js.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;          
    $(".equalize").each(function(){
      if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
    });         
    $(".equalize").height(maxHeight);
  });
```

Here is a [**working demo**](http://www.bootply.com/cZMxyZMggQ) based on your code.

All what you have to do is giving the same class to each main `div` inside the col-*-*, and than run a `each()` function in js that give to them the same height (the max-one).

Your HTML structure should looks like that:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail equalize">

      <!-- your HTML content -->

    </div> <!-- /.thumbnail equalize -->
  </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
</div> <!-- /.container -->
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the same trick I described in this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571062/gap-in-bootstap-stacked-rows/24571644#24571644)**.

In your case, you'd change the media queries to look like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .portfolio>.clear:nth-child(4n+4)::before {
      content: '';
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .portfolio>.clear:nth-child(6n+6)::before {  
      content: '';
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
}
```

768px - 991px is the sm size, you have col-sm-2, so you want every 4th div to clear. 992px and above relates to the md size, where you have col-md-3, so you want every 6th div to clear at that size.  It's way easier than using the responsive resets, although it's based on the exact same premise.

P.S. I added a div with the row class inside your container (because you need one inside a container otherwise you will have double padding on the outside) and I also gave it a class of portfolio for easy targeting.  Here's your updated **[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/QKuWRjf77G)**.

Comment: this seems quite ugly as you're rewriting mediaqueries that are originally defined by bootstrap, and manually changing the number of items in a row, additionally to what's defined by `.col-md-*`, for instance.

Comment: @igorsantos07 There's no rewriting of the media queries that are defined by Bootstrap, just a new class and corresponding CSS.  With this approach, you don't have to use the complicated markup for [Responsive Column Resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) to solve gap issues during wrapping.

Comment: You're still defining columns both in the markup and the CSS. The responsive resets are more flexible and makes much more sense than hardcoding stuff in the CSS :(

Answer (score 6):

you could use `clear: left` and apply it for each first child in row. For example if you have 4 items in row you can use:

```
.my-row>:nth-child(3n+1) {  
  clear:left;
  background-color: red; // just to see if the first item in row is matched
}
```

Comment: 3n+1 will check 1st,4th,7th...., i think it should be 4n+1 to check 1st,5th,9th....

Comment: Above sample didn't work for me, but it worked after changed like this, .my-row:nth-child(3n+1) {

Answer (score 2):

You can also do a CSS only clearfix like this. Simply add `auto-clear` to the `row`.

```
@media (min-width:1200px){
    .auto-clear .col-lg-1:nth-child(12n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-lg-2:nth-child(6n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-lg-3:nth-child(4n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-lg-4:nth-child(3n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-lg-6:nth-child(odd){clear:left;}
}
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){
    .auto-clear .col-md-1:nth-child(12n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-md-2:nth-child(6n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-md-6:nth-child(odd){clear:left;}
}
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){
    .auto-clear .col-sm-1:nth-child(12n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-sm-2:nth-child(6n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-sm-3:nth-child(4n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-sm-6:nth-child(odd){clear:left;}
}
@media (max-width:767px){
    .auto-clear .col-xs-1:nth-child(12n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-xs-2:nth-child(6n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-xs-3:nth-child(4n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+1){clear:left;}
    .auto-clear .col-xs-6:nth-child(odd){clear:left;}
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/lUbs1JgXUd

Comment: Inspired by this, I created I think a more thorough set and a hack.

Comment: http://www.codeply.com/go/Z0a63rJETm

The hack is that I'm using a CSS tie and ordering to get each size to ignore irrelevant rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many thumbnails wide is your arrangement, then you can use `<div class="row"></div>` to wrap thumbnails in groups of three (or N).

Otherwise, the workaround would be to set a fixed height for the thumbnail element. On your example

```
.thumbnail {
   height:420px; 
}
```

However, if your thumbnail height and text can vary a lot, then it will either look awkward or hide part of the img/label.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the `<div class="row"></div>`
Have a look at this http://www.bootply.com/6bIZkSGcA1

Is this what you wanted.??

P.S. This will directly limit the boundaries to a row.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Sorry that I wasn't clear, but I would like my solution to support various number of items in a row, depending on the screen size. That means I don't know where to put a new row. I updated my question.

Comment: @haimlit as you want to support range of columns that .clearfix is the perfect solution.