# Bootstrap grid not behaving when wrapping on smaller screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've found this issue in a number of places (eg: [Bootstrap: Dyamic columns with container-fluid and row not wrapping properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100547/bootstrap-dyamic-columns-with-container-fluid-and-row-not-wrapping-properly)), and every time it's a matter of adding a `clearfix` div in the location where some size screens will be wrapping, but I'm already doing that.

[image: misaligned icons]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block bottom10" src="/assets/filetypes/pdf.png" alt="Pdf">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block bottom10" src="/assets/filetypes/doc.png" alt="Doc">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block bottom10" src="/assets/filetypes/html.png" alt="Html">
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block bottom10" src="/assets/filetypes/mp3.png" alt="Mp3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block bottom10" src="/assets/filetypes/mov.png" alt="Mov">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block bottom10" src="/assets/filetypes/ppt.png" alt="Ppt">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do your icons have the same height?

Comment: Yes. All identical height.

Comment: i asked because this side effect happens only when you have different height columns. Here is the test with the same height img http://plnkr.co/edit/o3Zn6RfSMwGfhSixgost?p=preview

Comment: It turns out they are not quite the same size. MOV & HTML are 1px shorter than the others. Still doesn't explain why the clearfix div is not resolving the issue though??

Comment: your clearfix class is applied only for mobile devices so I assume you are checking on sm size devices. Remove visible-xs-block class.

Comment: I can just test by resizing the window, but yes I've tested on mobile devices also. And yes, I've done testing w/ and w/o the clearfix div.

Comment: I resized the two images that were off by 1px and that resolved the issue. Not particularly satisfying -- the clearfix should resolve according to documentation, but good enough.

Comment: I mean <div class="clearfix"></div> should resolve your issue as well. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

**Dan**, Hi there. It is clear that the `clearfix` is not helping you here, when the 3rd image is 1px smaller in height.
So to get around this if not making all images the same size, just use 2 `rows`.
Each row holds 3 images.

This code works for what you need here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Bootstrap grid not behaving when wrapping on smaller screens</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
<style>
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.spacer {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}    

.bottom10 {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }   
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    
<div class="container col-lg-12 spacer"></div>
        
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block bottom10" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/nature" alt="Pdf">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block bottom10" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/nature" alt="Doc">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block bottom10" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/39/nature" alt="Html">
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block bottom10" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/nature" alt="Mp3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block bottom10" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/nature" alt="Mov">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block bottom10" src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/nature" alt="Ppt">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    

    
</body>
</html>
```

[image: align images]