# Using grid in bootstrap 3 making a image gallery,using class col-lg-4 and adding 6 images in a single row, I am getting blank white spaces

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am newbie in **CSS and Bootstrap** and was trying to create a image gallery using Bootstrap Grid In which I am using One `row` class and under which i am using `col-lg-4` class for 3 columns in the container and if i am using 2 separate rows then the grid is working as i want.

but if i am using only one row class then the first 3 images are arranged properly as i want and if i am adding the fourth image in the same row then the image should automatically move into the second row and it is moving in second row too but in the second column not the first. Due to this reason the images are not correctly positioned. Any one can explain? and tell me what i am doing wrong?

below is the html code.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue";
}

.navbar-brand {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.nav {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Linking Bootstrap CSS -->

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- LINKING JQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Linking Bootstrap JAVASCRIPT -->

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#bs-nav-demo"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><strong>J.Photography</strong></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav-demo">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>The Image gallery</h1>
        <p>A bunch of beautiful Pictures from Around the Globe!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img
              src="https://d37b3blifa5mva.cloudfront.net/000_clients/1431025/page/1431025kkXelCOx.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img
              src="https://d37b3blifa5mva.cloudfront.net/000_clients/1431025/page/1431025Oq0YQLZZ.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img
              src="https://d37b3blifa5mva.cloudfront.net/000_clients/1431025/page/1431025u5zYFC6n.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img
              src="https://d37b3blifa5mva.cloudfront.net/000_clients/1431025/page/1431025kkXelCOx.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img
              src="https://d37b3blifa5mva.cloudfront.net/000_clients/1431025/page/1431025Oq0YQLZZ.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img
              src="https://d37b3blifa5mva.cloudfront.net/000_clients/1431025/page/1431025u5zYFC6n.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the images you added have different height, try give your image a fixed height to get aligned equally.

Comment: What if i don't want to change the height of the images? is there any work around to get rid of these white spaces?

Comment: hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915492/how-to-have-multiple-columns-in-bootstrap-row) will help.