# Bootstrap panels not aligned as I wish

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap for my webpage and having trouble with aligning panels.
I have many panels not all in the same size and they do not align as I would like them to do.
I would like to have panel three directly below panel 1.
.

[my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVSUX.png)

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6 pull left">
 <div class="panel panel-warning">
  <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">1</h3></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App 1_2</a>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-6 pull left">
 <div class="panel panel-danger">
  <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">2</h3></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App 2_3</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App 2_4</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App 2_5</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App 2_6</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App 2_7</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App 2_8</a>
        
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div> 
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6 pull left">
 <div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">3</h3></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App 3_1</a>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: And what order should the panels be in when the columns collapse?

Comment: In correct order, that is 1 2 3

Comment: I've never used `clearfix` but I think that might be the right direction for you to go. Heres an example on another SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939104/clear-rows-when-doing-multi-responsive-columns-bootstrap-3

Comment: The correct way to use `<div class="col-md-*"></div>` is inside a `<div class="row"></div>` by the way