# Modify Django for loop every four iterations

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a calendar generated by Django and styled with Bootstrap.
Here is the code in the Django template :

```
<div class="content">
  {% for month in period.get_months %}
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="row row-centered">
        <button class="btn btn-custom active" href="{% url "month_calendar" calendar.slug %}{% querystring_for_date month.start 2 %}">{{month.name}}</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {% month_table calendar month "small" %}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Now, since months have a different number of weeks they have different heights I would like to avoid something like this:
[image]

I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24572059/2314737) that the best solution would be to use a `clearfix`.

So, how can I modify the for loop in my template so that Django inserts an extra line `<div class="clearfix"></div>` every four items?

Comment: Have you seen the [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django templates for loop store current index in `forloop.counter` variable. You can read about this in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for). So you can try to change you code like this:

```
<div class="content">
  {% for month in period.get_months %}
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="row row-centered">
        <button class="btn btn-custom active" href="{% url "month_calendar" calendar.slug %}{% querystring_for_date month.start 2 %}">{{month.name}}</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {% month_table calendar month "small" %}
      </div>
    </div>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: HI. I'm not at all familiar with the % notation Django. I tried your code which makes sense but I get an error `Could not parse the remainder: '%' from '%'`

Comment: Hi, I fixed my answer, try it now

Comment: Now I'm getting the error message `'endfor', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Comment: Sorry it's typo I closed if block using endfor block instead of endif.

Comment: Ok, got it and it works! (except maybe one should skip the 0 counter because right now the month of january is in its own row)