# Bootstrap label.col-md-3 div.col-md-3 wrapping strangely

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to organise a display form using .net MVC and bootstrap - however, getting some odd bootstrap wrapping behavior.

I have the following code;

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.People.Count(); i++)
{
    var person = Model.People[i];
    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => person.Name) @(i + 1)</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => person.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
}
```

**What I'm expecting is a layout kinda like this:**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Person 1:</td>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Person 2:</td>
    <td>Fred</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Person 3:</td>
    <td>Sally</td>
    <td>Person 4:</td>
    <td>etc</td>
  </tr>
```

**But what im actually getting is like this:**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Person 1:</td>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Person 2:</td>
    <td>Fred</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Person 3:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sally</td>
    <td>Person 4:</td>
    <td>etc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Bootply for convenience](http://www.bootply.com/Eh3cv7HO5a)

I was under the impression that the bootstrap grid layout was simply supposed to wrap if it exceeds 12. So 4x col-md-6 would essentially produce 2 rows which both have 2 columns at 50%.

Can anyone offer any insight on why the wrapping behavior is acting strangely if the elements are an alternating label / div? Possibly a bug with bootstrap - considering their own documentation uses the same kind of markup ([e.g.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal))?

Was going to say:

Would changing the markup to have an extra div be my best approach?
e.g.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Person 1:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3>Joe</div>
```

But as it turns out - this also has the strange wrapping behaviour: [here](http://www.bootply.com/tCsFx9dPso)

Comment: use <div class="row"> to wrap every  4 columns separately or either use <div class="clearfix"> after every 4 columns

Comment: Kinda wanted to avoid having conditional rows (e.g. if (i % 2 == 0) <div class="row"> if(i % 2 != 0) </div>. I thought the default behavior was that it was supposed to wrap if the col exceeded 12 - and this is the case if it's only divs (without any labels at all - including nested). Moreso wanting to find out why the label upsets this behavior.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/UvAmO0hJ1k

Comment: you will get details why default behavior is not working on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598728/irregular-bootstrap-column-wrapping

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this issue

1.Wrapping every 12 column in single row separately. example.

```
<div class="row">
 
    <label class="col-md-3">Person 1</label>
  
  <div class="col-md-3">Joe</div>
 
    <label class="col-md-3">Person 1</label>
  
  <div class="col-md-3">Fred</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-3">Person 1</label>
  
  <div class="col-md-3">Sally</div>
  
    <label class="col-md-3">Person 1</label>
  
  <div class="col-md-3">etc</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-md-3">Person 1</label>
  
  <div class="col-md-3">Sally</div>
  
    <label class="col-md-3">Person 1</label>
  
  <div class="col-md-3">etc</div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://www.bootply.com/Eh3cv7HO5a)

2. Using clearfix class. add clearfix div after every 12 columns.

[Example](http://www.bootply.com/xB0BSEAaY6)

3. Using CSS apply similar Height to all columns if you are sure that no need of auto height.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
label {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3">Person 1</label>
  <div class="col-md-3">Joe</div>
  <label class="col-md-3">Person 2</label>
  <div class="col-md-3">Fred</div>
  <label class="col-md-3">Person 3</label>
  <div class="col-md-3">Sally</div>
  <label class="col-md-3">Person 4</label>
  <div class="col-md-3">etc</div>
</div>
```

[**Here you will get more details about this isssue.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598728/irregular-bootstrap-column-wrapping)

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it's to do with the margin-bottom of the label.

So it's essentially doing [this](http://www.bootply.com/Pzd2mAFSwu).

I'll probably just add a display: flex onto it - to force an equal height.
This will solve it until bootstrap 4 is released - as it will then be built using display: flex instead of float's anyway.

EDIT: I ended up fixing it with:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.People.Count(); i++)
{
    var person = Model.People[i];

    <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-6 col-form-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => person.Name) @(i + 1)</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => person.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
}
```

This makes all label + displayfor columns (outer col-md-6 and row divs) the same height (i.e. the height of the label) - so there isnt any overhang for the next column to float left onto. Meaning that it now wraps correctly.